# How to use JmsTemplate.sendAndReceive

Tags: jms, spring-jms, jmstemplate

I want to get sync response from jmsTemplate.sendAndReceive:

```
    Message responseMessage = producer.produceAndReceive(gzip, mestype, uploadFile.getName(), uploadFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

It calls produceAndReceive in another class:

```
  @Override
  public Message produceAndReceive(final byte[] data, final String type, final String name, final String archivePath) {
    jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(20000);
    return jmsTemplate.sendAndReceive(SAPPI_EXPORT_QUEUE, new MessageCreator() {
      @Override
      public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
        String msgId = UUIDGen.getUUID();
        BytesMessage message = session.createBytesMessage();
        message.writeBytes(data);
        message.setStringProperty(ISapProducer.IDOC_TYPE, type);
        message.setStringProperty(ISapProducer.ORIGIN_FILE_NAME, name);
        message.setStringProperty(ISapProducer.MESSAGE_ID, msgId);
        message.setStringProperty(ISapProducer.ARCHIVE_PATH, archivePath);

        message.setJMSReplyTo(session.createTemporaryQueue());
        message.setJMSCorrelationID(msgId);
        return message;
      }
    });
  }
```

after it step I suppose that message already placed in queue. I have @JmsListener method, that 'listen to' this queue:

```
  @Override
  @JmsListener(destination = "myqueue.export")
  public void consume(final Message message) throws ServerException {
     // some logic here
         final HttpStatus httpStatus = client.send(gzip, idocType, documentFileName, messageId, archivePath);
        jmsTemplate.send(message.getJMSReplyTo(), new MessageCreator() {
          @Override
          public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
            Message responseMsg = session.createTextMessage(httpStatus.toString());
            responseMsg.setJMSCorrelationID(message.getJMSCorrelationID());
            return responseMsg;
          }
        });
    // some logic here

  }
```

Here I send http-request to remote system and try to use httpStatus at response message for sendAndReceive() method. But in responseMessage always null. And it looks like it works asynchronously.

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works fine for me...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So53506177Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So53506177Application.class, args);
    }

    private final SimpleMessageConverter converter = new SimpleMessageConverter();

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
        return args -> {
            jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(20000);
            Message received = jmsTemplate.sendAndReceive("foo", new MessageCreator() {

                @Override
                public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                    String msgId = "foo";
                    TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("foo");
                    message.setJMSCorrelationID(msgId);
                    return message;
                }
            });
            System.out.println("Reply: " + this.converter.fromMessage(received));
        };
    }

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @JmsListener(destination = "foo")
    public void consume(final Message message) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Received: " + this.converter.fromMessage(message));
        jmsTemplate.send(message.getJMSReplyTo(), new MessageCreator() {

            @Override
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                Message responseMsg = session.createTextMessage("bar");
                responseMsg.setJMSCorrelationID(message.getJMSCorrelationID());
                return responseMsg;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

and

```
Received: foo
Reply: bar
```

However, while it doesn't affect the result, you shouldn't create your own `replyTo` - the template creates its own after the `MessageCreator` exits (and consumes from it). It also deletes it when done:

```
@Nullable
protected Message doSendAndReceive(Session session, Destination destination, MessageCreator messageCreator)
        throws JMSException {

    Assert.notNull(messageCreator, "MessageCreator must not be null");
    TemporaryQueue responseQueue = null;
    MessageProducer producer = null;
    MessageConsumer consumer = null;
    try {
        Message requestMessage = messageCreator.createMessage(session);
        responseQueue = session.createTemporaryQueue();
        producer = session.createProducer(destination);
        consumer = session.createConsumer(responseQueue);
        requestMessage.setJMSReplyTo(responseQueue);
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Sending created message: " + requestMessage);
        }
        doSend(producer, requestMessage);
        return receiveFromConsumer(consumer, getReceiveTimeout());
    }
    finally {
        JmsUtils.closeMessageConsumer(consumer);
        JmsUtils.closeMessageProducer(producer);
        if (responseQueue != null) {
            responseQueue.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

You can also simplify your listener:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "foo")
public String consume(final Message message) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Received: " + this.converter.fromMessage(message));
    return "bar";
}
```